# FFMPEG overlay video with time shift or offset

Tags: ffmpeg

I've figured out how to composite 2 videos using the overlay command, but was wondering if there is also a way to offset or shift the 2nd video in time, so you don't see the overlayed video until after a certain amount of time has elapsed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, use the [`itsoffset`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Main-options) option to offset a particular stream.

See my answer here for specific usage examples: [Fix an m4v video that has lagging audio (audio and video out of sync)](https://superuser.com/questions/496653/fix-an-m4v-video-that-has-lagging-audio-audio-and-video-out-of-sync/496797#496797)

You want to supply two input files, offset one with `-itsoffset` by specifying a (positive) delay value, use the `-filter_complex` overlay, and then use the `-map` options to select the proper streams to put it back together.

Note that you cannot use `-c copy` to copy video streams – you will have to tell FFmpeg to re-encode.