# AVI file: Audio getting GRADUALLY out of sync

Tags: audio, avi

I have an AVI video where audio is **GRADUALLY** out of sync.

In the beginning, audio is **correctly in sync** , but during the film, it gets **more and more out of sync**. After 90 minutes, the gap is around 3 seconds!

I know there are methods for fixing a **constant delay**, but can a **gradual error** also be fixed?

**Stream 0: Video**

- Codec H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part 10) (H264)
- 1280x720
- Rate: 50 Hz
- Decoded Format: Planar 4:2:0 YUV

**Stream 1: Audio**

- Codec: MPEG Audio Layer 1/2/3 (mpga)
- Stereo
- Rate: 48000 Hz
- Bit Rate: 192 kB/s

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tool to fix video that's out of sync with audio?](http://superuser.com/questions/285917/tool-to-fix-video-thats-out-of-sync-with-audio)

Comment: @Brian My video is **gradually** out of sync, in contrast to a **constant** delay.

Comment: There's a couple answers there which may fit your situation, see http://superuser.com/a/414143/496428 specifically.

Comment: @Brian Well OK, that answer is more than 3 years old. Possibly, meanwhile there is some new tool available ?

Comment: @SQLPolice Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic).